# Getting HTTP error 500, while running BPEL project in Eclipse with Apache ODE

Tags: java, eclipse, bpel, apache-ode

I am using Eclipse Neon, Apache Tomcat 6, Apache ODE 1.3.6 and Java 8. Java 8 is working fine in the Java perspective of Eclipse.

I am learning BPEL concepts from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vW--eCxf_w

At time 3:11 it says to right click on WSDL file and test with web services explorer. In video, its working fine. But I am getting these errors:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /wse/wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp. Reason:

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.util.Enumeration cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.lang.Throwable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.io.IOException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.lang.Exception cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.util.List cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Only a type can be imported. java.util.Enumeration resolves to a package

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The hierarchy of the type wsexplorer_jsp is inconsistent

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The hierarchy of the type wsexplorer_jsp is inconsistent

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type wsexplorer_jsp must implement the inherited abstract method JspSourceDependent.getDependants()

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Enumeration cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getParameterNames() from the type ServletRequest refers to the missing type Enumeration

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getContextPath() from the type HttpServletRequest refers to the missing type String

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
java.util.List cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
java.util.List cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
_jspx_dependants cannot be resolved to a variable

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
java.io.IOException cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
No exception of type ServletException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Object cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method setContentType(String) from the type ServletResponse refers to the missing type String

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getPageContext(Servlet, ServletRequest, ServletResponse, String, boolean, int, boolean) from the type JspFactory refers to the missing type String

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getAttribute(String) from the type ServletContext refers to the missing type Object

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.io.Writer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.util.Locale cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getLocale() from the type ServletResponse refers to the missing type Locale

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 23 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getId() from the type HttpSession refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 34 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 34 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 35 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getAttribute(String, int) from the type JspContext refers to the missing type Object

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 35 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method setAttribute(String, Object, int) from the type JspContext refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 35 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 35 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 69 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 69 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 70 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 70 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 71 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 71 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 72 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getSessionId() from the type Controller refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 72 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 72 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 86 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 86 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 87 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method include(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, String, JspWriter, boolean) from the type JspRuntimeLibrary refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 87 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 87 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 88 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getMessage(String) from the type MessageProvider refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 88 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 88 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 93 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 93 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 94 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 94 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 94 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getMessage(String) from the type MessageProvider refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 96 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 96 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 96 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getMessage(String) from the type MessageProvider refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 96 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 96 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getPathWithContext(String) from the type Controller refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 96 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 96 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 97 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
String cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 97 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 97 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getMessage(String) from the type MessageProvider refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 97 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 97 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method getPathWithContext(String) from the type Controller refers to the missing type String

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 97 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 97 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 97 in the jsp file: /wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method write(String) is undefined for the type JspWriter

Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.9.v20160517
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't usually go with eclipse based deployments for ODE. It's always better to do it the manual way. Anyways, ODE 1.3.7 has been released few days ago. So, wanted to checkout the integration with Eclipse Neon. 
Environment: Linux: Kubuntu 17.04, jdk1.8.0_92, Eclipse Neon, ODE 1.3.7 war, Tomcat 8.5.16.

- Make sure in eclipse Installed JREs -> runtime location is pointing to JDK installation directory and not the JRE directory.
- Deploy the ODE war in tomcat 8.5.16
- In eclipse add the ODE runtime server as explained in the video you are referring to.
- Under the Server view in eclipse "double click" on the ode server that you have just added. It will open the config editor, look for "Open Launch Configuration" which is in blue colour and click it.
- It will open the Launch editor, go the Classpath menu tab. Click on "Add Jars" button and traverse to tomcat's bin directory to find bootstrap.jar and tomcat-juli.jar. Select them and add it to the classpath entries and save.
- Follow the instructions as depicted in the video to deploy your bpel project.
- Open the webservice test editor to fire the request.

ODE 1.3.7 has new AngularJS based web console.
Happy ODEing :)

http://ode.apache.org/getting-ode.html